# From within an ember component life cycle hook, how can I determine if the component is being invoked in block form?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Per the [Ember guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/composing-components/), you can determine if a component is being rendered in block format from within the template using the `hasBlock` keyword:

```
// foo-component.hbs
{{#if hasBlock}}
block mode
{{else}}
something else
{{/if}}
```

How do I do this from within `foo-component.js`?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

 export default Ember.Component.extend({
         didInitAttrs: function() {
                 // hasBlock is not defined here
                 if ( this.get('hasBlock') ) {

                 }
         }
 });
```

Comment: Did you try it in other hooks?

Comment: hasBlock cannot be accessed from the JS file.  Per Ember discussion: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11741

Comment: I did Gennady. Thanks sbatson, that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

You could check for `template` property of Component, but such behavior is deprecated:

```
if (this.get('template')) {
   console.log('Component has block!');
}
```

[Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/8a8a408e3a5946856d5b)

Answer (score 0):

Per sbatson's comment, using `hasBlock` in the template is not supported.